# Is it safe to put password into request object

Tags: node.js, http, security, https

I want to put user's password into request object for accessing it next request object. Is it secure?

For example :

We have a route like "http://localhost/my_bank".

And there are two middlewares before accessing to route.

First middleware checks user's password and if it is true puts password into request object and continues for second middleware.

Second middleware gets user password with request.password and continues the process.

Comment: Poor detailed questions asks for a poor detailed answer: yes

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your question means.  Please include relevant code to illustrate the problem exactly and show what "next request" means.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the request object that is passed to a middleware handler such as in Express like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
     // do something here
     req.password = someData;
     next();
});
```

Then, there's nothing particularly unsafe about that.  In fact, if you were using `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()` to parse an incoming form that contains the password, then that middleware already put the password into `req.body.password` or some similarly named field.  Thus, it's already in the `req` object and this is a common usage.

So, there's nothing inherently unsafe about putting a password in the `req` object as long as you aren't passing the `req` object to functions/code that shouldn't have access to the password.

Comment: Actually, it would be better if I asked the question like following. Is it unsafe if I put something that is not in the incoming request object into the request object? For example first middlewares compares the passwords and if password is ture, it puts account credentials the request object like "request.account_credentials" and continues for second middleware and second middleware gets account credentials with request.account_credentials and continues the process. Is that safe?

Comment: @mka - The answer is the same, whether it's a password or some other credential.  The `req` object is private except to things you pass it to or configure as middleware.  So, it's under your control who sees the `req` object.